# How to System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, custom-controls, imagebutton

I want to build custom controls in ASP.NET MVC 3. I want to create a button to which I can pass different parameters such as CSS class name and so on. However I want to be able to track events on it such as onClick or onHover...

How can I do it? Please I'm stuck with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a HtmlHelper like:

```
public static class Helpers {
    public static MvcHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper html, string id, string url) {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("a");

        builder.MergeAttribute("href", url);
        builder.MergeAttribute("id", id);
        builder.AddCssClass("custom-button");

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

In the view:

```
@Html.Button("CustomButton", "http://localhost")
```

The JS using JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".custom-button").click(function() {
        // This will handle all the click events of the buttons
    });

    $("#CustomButton").click(function() {
        // This will handle the click event on the specific button
    });
});
```

As Darin said, there are no more user controls as we had in asp.net webforms, and according to me that's a very good thing.

So the code above is a way to build a "user control".

Answer (score 2):

Server side controls and events no longer exist in ASP.NET MVC. If you want to track events such as `oncilck` and `onhover` you could use javascript. Also you could use HTML helpers. Simply forget about the `System.Web.UI` namespace in an ASP.NET MVC application.